# Should the following join structure work for a CakePHP find?

Tags: mysql, cakephp, search, join

Is the following join structure correctly formatted to work with a CakePHP find? This doesn't seem to be working when I use it along with conditions and my gut tells me that the structure is off. I'm new to joins, so any help is appreciated.

```
'joins' => array(
    (int) 0 => array(
        'table' => 'cheeses_milk_sources',
        'alias' => 'CheesesMilkSource',
        'type' => 'INNER',
        'conditions' => array(
            (int) 0 => 'Cheese.id = CheesesMilkSource.cheese_id'
        )
    ),
    (int) 1 => array(
        'table' => 'milk_sources',
        'alias' => 'MilkSource',
        'type' => 'INNER',
        'conditions' => array(
            (int) 0 => 'CheesesMilkSource.milk_source_id = MilkSource.id',
            'CheesesMilkSource.milk_source_id' => '1'
        )
    )
),
'conditions' => array(
    'AND' => array(
        (int) 0 => array(
            'Cheese.cheese_producer_id' => (int) 35
        ),
        (int) 1 => array(
            'Cheese.active' => (int) 1
        )
    )
),
```

Comment: what result are you getting ? what is the query being produced? if the query being produced is not what you want? can you write out the query you want ?

Comment: Are you writing those joins by yourself? If so: why? Cake is based on associations, also see Containable behaviour. It is not likely to write those kind of joins except when really optimising an application.

Comment: I'm familiar with Containable and I'm not using it because I need to paginate the results.

Answer (score 1):

The confusing part is

```
    'conditions' => array(
        (int) 0 => 'CheesesMilkSource.milk_source_id = MilkSource.id',
        'CheesesMilkSource.milk_source_id' => '1'
    )
```

You are mixing an array element without a key with one with a key equal to `CheesesMilkSource.milk_source_id`.

if you need to specify two conditions on the join, do it like

```
    'conditions' => array(
        'CheesesMilkSource.milk_source_id = MilkSource.id AND CheesesMilkSource.milk_source_id = 1'
    )
```

perhaps the next snippet will equally work, but I'm not sure and can't test it at the moment - let me know if it does with a comment.

```
    'conditions' => array(
        'CheesesMilkSource.milk_source_id = MilkSource.id',
        'CheesesMilkSource.milk_source_id = 1'
    )
```

But since you're joining the tables, maybe you should put `CheesesMilkSource.milk_source_id = 1` in the general conditions of the find:

```
'conditions' => array(
   'Cheese.cheese_producer_id' => 35,
   'Cheese.active' => 1,
   'CheesesMilkSource.milk_source_id' => 1,
)
```

Notice you don't need to specify `AND` as this is the default way of joining conditions.

Comment: I like the last example as this seems the cleanest. Thanks.